# addional gradle tasks not appearing

Tags: java, windows, gradle, build.gradle

Please excuse me if this question has been asked before.

I am installing Gradle on my Windows laptop. I placed my installation in Program Files and chagned the `PATH` envionment variable as required. When I type `gradle` in the command prompt everything is OK. Now I am starting to create the build.gradle file and the first thing I have placed in there is `apply plugin:'java'` which is supposed to bring up additional tasks when I type the `gradle tasks` command but no additional tasks are appearing. I am concerned that I am not placing the file in the right place so I have tried placing it in the bin directory and the top level Gradle directory.

If it helps this is what I see when I type `gradle tasks`:

[image: What I see when I run <code>gradle tasks</code> both before and after created the build.gradle file]

I tried adding the `--all` option but this did not yield any further tasks.

The steps I am following can be found here:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/ (I'm using this site as I eventually want to install the Spring framework too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `gradle tasks` from the same directory that contains `build.gradle`. Never place the latter below the Gradle install dir; it belongs into the base dir of the project you are trying to build.